# Auto restart beaglebone network

Tags: node.js, tcpclient, beagleboneblack

I am developing a service in a BeagleBone Black. It starts at boot after network connection. That service runs a node.js script, which is a TCP client. When I am working with the BeagleBone connected to net, if I loose the connection (maybe a light cut or whatever), I have to manually restart the network. Is there a way to do it automatically from the node.js code? It is an embedded solution, so, I would not be able to restart it if something happens.

I think that other solution could be rebooting the BBB when node detects a fail in the network. Couldn't it?